# Oracle view V$WORKAREA

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have to look for information about the view V$SQL_WORKAREA, and I couldn't find much about it from the Oracle Documentation.
Hope you can help me with some information about the View and its columns. Thank you in Advance.

Comment: No hint of why you think you might need to look at this view or what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full dexcription of the view `V$SQL_WORKAREA` in [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10755/dynviews_2109.htm).
You can also use `desc` command as usual:

```
desc V$SQL_WORKAREA;
```